# The Last character alphabetized in online games

Tags: optimization

I am trying to get last place in a Quizziz game. There are several people with a 0 score, and the person in last place has a z. What is the last character that is alphabetized by the computer?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail and clarity about your question. This may not even be suitable for SO.

Comment: This is probably sorted by a [`Lexicographic Order`](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap92/ch92_2.html), like in a dictionary. `z` is the last character in this order and `zz` will come after `z` so if you want to be the last your name should be `zzz...zzz` as long as you can. If you are allowed to put chars other than the alphabet than this char should actually be `~` (according to the [`Ascii Table`](http://www.asciitable.com/)).